# Unread Inbox Color Sends Wrong Message in Competitive Environment

Tags: feature-request, design, notifications, top-bar

[image]

Having designed many user interfaces it is understood that the intent of using the color `red`. It makes *that* something stand out, it asks for a *take notice* effect. Understood. I am proposing changing that color to `green`. There are subtle psychological aspects which may be overlooked and that might not be what the helpful direction of StackOverflow (SO) intends.

Answering questions on SO is *by its nature* a competitive endeavor. The comments one receives in actuality are mostly constructive criticisms. But when one actually reads the message *cold*, meaning without being able to read emotion of the response, one tends to lean toward a negative meaning or connotation; resulting in a wrongly *inflamed* response to the response.

If the box changed to `green` then any future message would not *start out as* the `red flag` of warning and not *amp* up the user to a possible negative response to the response.

Subtle...I await the `green` responses.

Comment: Is there, perhaps, a consideration for those who are colorblind?

Comment: I hope I didn't vandalize your title too much :)

Comment: @nicael The changed de-emphasized the intent of the article, which is not *just* a color change for change, but it removed the *why*.

Comment: For a feature request, the title is the change/result, the body is the why/reason

Comment: Also, why are you marking colours as code keywords?

Comment: @random Yes the body is the supporting arguments, but an effective title, whether in a newspaper, a blog or even a thesis, needs to grab attention for the *right* reasons and runs in unison with the supporting arguments of the body. I consider it, my first argument, of the work. As to the keyword colors, just habit from SO. The keyword colors are not necessarily relevant; but provide an `actual` effect for the reader of SO to know it is a code change.

Answer (score 6):

> it asks for a *take notice* effect

It should, shouldn't it (the main function of inbox indicator)? You have unread messages (bounty expiring soon, etc), comments, or something else.  Inbox means something **important**, not "you have new rep changes, it is positive :)". I don't want the color to be changed because it contrasts with recent achievements (red <-> green). I wouldn't like it to be the same color as shiny "+10", because it is not often shows something **as** positive as rep indicator often shows.

[image]

So what would we get with green inbox indicator?

A new rep change indicator, just without "+".

[image]

Another variant (probably the best), which I would agree with, [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242097/unread-inbox-color-sends-wrong-message-in-competitive-environment/242100#comment791622_242100) by Shog9:

[image]

Comment: Make rep blue, and mod flags red!

Comment: I added the snapshot to support your argument, I hope you don't mind. Your thought is well taken, maybe green would not be *the color*, but maybe an orange instead for the inbox?

Comment: @Omega Thanks very much. I also used it to illustrate the look with your suggestion :)

Comment: @fredley And diamond should be pink, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Omega Orange is indicator of new suggested edits pending review, try again :D

Comment: I fully support orange - [bow down to your new overlords](http://www.metaltech.me)

Comment: Plaid or nothing.

Comment: @Shog I vote for plaid.

Comment: @Shog http://i.stack.imgur.com/ox9Lv.png

Comment: @Shog edited to add more high-res images and high-res proposal of the previous variant.